# Where can I get xmkmf for RedHat Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm trying to build GLUT, but I fail on:

> xmkmf: Command not found

Where can I find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the `imake` package, which you can install with yum via `yum install imake` or just download, e.g. from http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=imake.

Answer (score 2):

if imake is not installed, install it from pkgs.org

http://pkgs.org/search/?keyword=imake